# Correct Image Size for Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a jumbotron container in bootstrap and trying to use an image as the background.  However, it seems like all images distort as the screen size changes or don't display the correct part of the photo.  Is there a correct size I should set save my image in?  Or a way to get rid of/minimize distortion on screen resize?  I can show you my code if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default{
    background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
.under {
    border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
.size {
    width: 300px;
}
.jumbotron{
    height: 400px;
    background: url("../images/parakeet.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}

HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Button nav for small screens -->

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
<!-- Brand name -->

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

<!-- Makes nav not expand on resize -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

<!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<!-- Dropdown menu -->
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<!-- Non dropdown -->
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
</nav>
      <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <h1>Website Heading</h1>
      <p>Information about the website!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

            </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass btn-lg"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-lg"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"I can show you my code if necessary."_ Yes please

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: This is normal since you use `background: cover for the image` 
However, you can tweak which part to show with background-position ^_^.

Comment: so what would minimizing the distortion be? It only can do what you are telling it to. How do you want it to display max height, max width, repeated, scaled, something else?

Comment: Show us the image you're using (`parakeet.jpg`)

Comment: http://bsnscb.com/cute-parrot-wallpapers/40073771.html

Comment: if you don't want a distorted image then don't set background to cover. But you will loose your responsiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. Now you need to play with `background-position`
Now if you run this code. You will see an image with some cute dogs. Now on smaller devices you will see the 3 middle dogs. Why? because the `background-position` is set to 50% on x and 50% on y (The center of the image)

Let's say that on mobiles you want to show the right most puppy with the black head. That is simple you just set `background-position` to 100% and 50%.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default{
    background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
.under {
    border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(66, 134, 244);
}
.size {
    width: 300px;
}
.jumbotron{
    height: 400px;
    background: url("https://puppydogweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/54_2383_Cute-Puppies-puppies-16094619-1280-800.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Button nav for small screens -->

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
<!-- Brand name -->

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>

<!-- Makes nav not expand on resize -->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

<!-- Menu -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<!-- Dropdown menu -->
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
<!-- Non dropdown -->
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    </div>
</nav>
      <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <h1>Website Heading</h1>
      <p>Information about the website!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

            </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass btn-lg"></span>

            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                <h2>Text</h2>
                <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-lg"></span>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

So everything that has resolution < tablet resolution will see the black head puppy.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .jumbotron{
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  Would I have to set differing background-positions for different screen sizes?

Comment: Could you give me an example of how you would do this?  Marked your answer as correct

Comment: That makes sense!  I've seen that in templates but never understood it.  So a tablet has a screen size of 768px?  To ensure complete responsivity would you need to set the @media for different max-widths?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  Are there other common screen sizes you should design for, like 768px?

Comment: I usually use this. But it all depends on the design. These points might not work for all websites.

`  "phone":        400px,`
`  "phone-wide":   480px,`
 ` "phablet":      560px,`
`  "tablet-small": 640px,`
`  "tablet":       768px,`
`  "tablet-wide":  1024px,`
 ` "desktop":      1248px,`
 ` "desktop-wide": 1440px`

Answer (score 1):

you should add the following rules to the .jumbotron

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the jumbotron scale and always show the full background image, make the height of the jumbotron `0`, then use a percentage of padding that matches the aspect ratio of the image to create that same amount of padding in the jumbotron.

The image is 1920x1080. Represented as a percentage, 1080/1920 = 56.25%. Applied as a top or bottom padding, that will make jumbotron match that aspect ratio. Then you can absolutely position the text inside the jumbotron wherever you want. I introduced an element called `.jumbotron-text` for that.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgb(66, 134, 244);
}

.under {
  border-bottom: 15px solid rgb(66, 134, 244);
}

.size {
  width: 300px;
}

.jumbotron-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 56.25% 0 0 !important;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/OXMygdn.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">

        <!-- Button nav for small screens -->

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
        <!-- Brand name -->

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Makes nav not expand on resize -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

        <!-- Menu -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          <!-- Dropdown menu -->
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Non dropdown -->
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="jumbotron text-center under">
    <div class="jumbotron-text">
      <h1>Website Heading</h1>
      <p>Information about the website!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf size"></span>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass btn-lg"></span>

      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <h2>Text</h2>
        <p>More text describing the heading!</p>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-lg"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

While waiting for the code, did you add the responsive class to the image tag?

`<img src="picture.jpg" class="img-responsive">`

Comment: the image is a background of the jumbotron the responsive class will not do much in this case